# Insert a vector into a specific location in 2d vector in c++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I just started using c++, so I am still new to vectors and data structures. I'm wondering how to I add a int value into a specific index location of 2d vector. For example, I have a multidimensional vector "chessboard" initialized like:

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

How do I use the `insert()` method to insert a integer value 1 into say the x,y index [4,3] so It looks like this:

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 0 0

This Is my code so far:

```
vector<vector<int>> board(boardsize, vector<int> (boardsize, 0));
int x = 4; // x position for value to be inserted
int y = 3; // y position for value to be inserted
```

Comment: [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) doesn't do what you think. It increases the length of the vector, which makes the board non-rectangular after the call. What you want is `board[x][y] = 1`.

Answer (score 4):

In order to change a value of an element of a `std::vector`, you can use [`std::vector::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at).
For example in your case of a vector containing vectors:

```
board[x][y] = 1;
```

**Note** that [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) does **not** modify an existing element, but rather adds a new element (or elements) to the vector. This is **not** what you want since you set the final desired size of the vector upon construction.

**A side note:** better to avoid `using namespace std;` - see here: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).